# "Error validating formula" when adding Computed Column with CONVERT(DATE, column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, calculated-columns

I am trying to add a computed column to a table via SSMS - I'd rather care not to get into the details on why the base column is a `VARCHAR(10)` and not a `DATE` and no, I'm not interested in changing it.

When I enter the formula `CONVERT(DATE, [charDob])` in the table designer SSMS reports:

> Error validating the the formula for column `charDobTyped`.

Using the formula `[charDob]` "works" as expected, meaning the column is bound correctly. Also the formula `CONVERT(DATE, '2001')` "works" as expected - so there is something with using the column that is causing the error.

The original column is a `VARCHAR(10)` and contains NULL values *or* values that are otherwise convertible to `DATE`. The query `SELECT CONVERT(DATE,charDob) as dob FROM people` works as expected. Also, the error message is about "invalid formula" and not about a data conversion error, so I don't believe that inconvertible is causing this.

I have already saved the table with the new computed column and a dummy value and reconnected to the database - this was to ensure that there was not an odd caching issue occurring, as sometimes occurs. The error persists independent of the persisted flag - if only it were that easy to turn off.

Comment: Have you tried using a proper `ALTER TABLE` statement instead of the UI which is riddled with all kinds of bugs? Or maybe you need to clarify what you mean by `try to *use* the formula`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ding ding ding. Point goes to you - yes, it does work correctly when doing it via DROP/ADD. (Silly me, I should have tried this sooner.) Post that as an answer for an accept/vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Management Studio is not the best way to perform most DDL. Please open a new query window and use:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.whatever ADD newcolumn AS (CONVERT(DATE, CharDob));
```

Here is the specific bug:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/291134/katmai-table-designer-cant-validate-computed-column-formula

"Next release" in this context is most certainly SQL Server 2012, so if you are using 2008 or 2008 R2 SSMS (why?), the fix won't apply to you.

Comment: On a side note, if one wants the date conversion to be deterministic, the style must be applied (e.g. `CONVERT(DATE,x,20)`) ..

Comment: @pst yes persistence has some additional requirements particularly with date/time types. Anyway glad the fix is simple for you. Suggest using the newer version of SSMS - lots of these little bugs are fixed and there are also a lot of improved features.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 (SSMS 13.0.16106.4 against SQL 12.0.4100.1). This is still a bug. An annoying one. I can't rearrange my columns because SSMS says the formula can't be validated even though I added them with T-SQL